# How do I make people able to hear a sound played using commands regardless of where in the world they are?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm making a map. i am trying to use the `/playsound` command. There is going to be a boss battle at the end, and I need my music disc to play. I know how to play a sound, but I want it so people can hear it no matter where they are in the final boss area. Because if they walk far enough away, they won't be able to hear it.

Comment: What commands are you using?

Comment: I'm using /playsound only. But I don't know if /execute would work for this.

Answer (score 1):

### Arguments Used

For the target selector use `@a` this will play the sound to all players. Then, for the volume argument, put in something like `999`, this will create a large sphere of audio.

### Example

I use a `/execute` to get the proper location of a player.

```
/execute @p ~ ~ ~ /playsound mob.enderdragon.growl @a ~ ~ ~ 999
```

Comment: I know that, but when they walk away, the sound will begin to quiet down, and eventually be silent until they go back to where they first heard the sound. And I need them to always hear the sound no matter where they are.

Comment: Is he talking about increasing the sound area then? Sorry I must have misunderstood.

Comment: No thats much better IMO. I originally flagged it because just saying use the @ selector seemed more like just basic command information rather than an answer to the OP. But your edit makes it clear the direction you were going with it. Thanks for taking the time to clarify!